# readMetadata returns nil records, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: api, metadata, page-layout

I'm able to list Layouts with listMetadata just fine. When I attempt to readMetadata for a Layout I get nil records back. Any ideas what might be happening? Thanks in advance for replying.

```
SOAP request: https://na16.salesforce.com/services/Soap/m/32.0/00Dj0000000Iq1IEAS
<env:Body>
  <readMetadata xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <type>Layout</type>
  <fullNames>Account-Account Layout</fullNames>
  </readMetadata>
</env:Body></env:Envelope>
```

The response I get is:

```
<readMetadataResponse>
  <result>
    <records xsi:nil="true"/>
  </result>
</readMetadataResponse>
```

Comment: Thanks @crop1645. No, <fullNames> is just an array of strings.
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_readMetadata.htm

Comment: comment deleted; I should have known better